# Using an Owl Carousel in a project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to use an owl carousel in my project but somehow nothing is showing and I do not know what is wrong with it. Can anyone help me understand what it is that I am doing wrong? I have followed the steps from this tutorial https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2 and I have also tried inspecting the element but no errors show up and also no carousel is visible.
Here is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7db147a51.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

here the js code:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 50,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    navText: [
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
  ],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer. Its working. You need to initalte owlCarousel like this `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();`.

check this [demo](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7db147a51.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
    }
}
})
});
</script>
</html>
```